# break a column in 2 on breakpoint md using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, breakpoints, bootstrap-5, card

I want to break the cards in a certain order on breakpoint -md. As shown below.

[image]

I hope the above image clears what I want to achieve. If possible it should be done using bootstrap and or minimal CSS.

The entire is written using BS5.

CODE up to now:

```css
.scroll_card_expense {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 700px;
}

.payee_card {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 465px;
}

.col_height {
  max-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container px-3">
  <div class="row flex-md-row-reverse py-3">

    <div class="col-md-6 col_height">
      <!-- LIGHT BLUE CARD-->
      <div class="order-md-1 card my-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- LIGHT BLUE CARD-->
      <!-- DARK BLUE CARD-->
      <div class="order-md-1 card my-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- DARK BLUE CARD-->
      <!-- GREEN CARD-->
      <div class="order-md-1 card my-2">
        <div class="card-body">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- GREEN CARD-->
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col_height">
      <!-- YELLOW CARD-->
      <div class="order-md-3 card my-2">
        <div class="card-body scroll_card_expense">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- YELLOW CARD-->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you change direction of div with class row you can do that. like this :

```
<div class="row flex-md-row-reverse py-3" dir="rtl">
   ...
  </div>
```

and in your css file :

```
.col_height {
  max-height: 800px;
  direction:ltr;
}
```